# Move data to a specified Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 columns, A, B and C.

A= list of names
B= the specific cells for each name
c= empty column I want to paste the names to

I cant seem to figure this out and the list of names in 1 sheet is much smaller than the list of names in the second.

edit: The names in A are not in order, column B lists what row to paste the name to in column C

Comment: What do you mean by the "specific cells for each name?"

Comment: The names in A are not in order, column B lists what row to paste the name to in column C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy randomly ordered data to a corresponding cell](http://superuser.com/questions/610207/copy-randomly-ordered-data-to-a-corresponding-cell)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you have a list of names in column A and a list of numbers in column B that indicate in what row in column C each name in column A should be displayed. You need a formula that will show the names in column A in the order determined by column B.

For example, if the word 'Alpha' is in cell A1 and the number 3 is in cell B1, then Alpha should be displayed in cell C3.

The following formula will produce that result.

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(C1),B:B,0),1)
```

This formula works in two steps:

- The `MATCH` function identifies the *row* in column B that matches the *row number* of each cell in column C. In the example shown below, cell C1 has a row number of 1; MATCH finds that value in the 2nd row of column B.
- The `INDEX` function then returns the value in column A for the row that `MATCH` found. So, in the example, 'Beta' is shown in cell C1, 'Kappa' in C2, and 'Alpha' in C3.

[image: worksheet example showing solution]

Just paste the formula in cell C1 (or the row in column C corresponding to the start of the list in column A) and copy it down to the last row of names.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want something as follows:

```
Data | Row | Output
-------------------
ValA |  3  |  ValC
ValB |  1  |  ValA
ValC |  2  |  ValB
```

To accomplish this, use the INDEX function on the third column, something along these lines

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$65536,B1)
```

The first argument specifies the range you want to look in (here I have specified part of the column A), and the second cell refers to the row to pick the data from.